# $D_vX$ is completely determined by $X$ restricted on any curve $r$ with $r'(0)=v,r(0)=p$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

I want to show given $v\in T_pM$, then $D_vX$ is completely determined by $X$ restricted to any curve $r$ with $r'(0)=v,r(0)=p$.

I have shown that if $r_1'(0)=r'_2(0)=v,$  then $D_{r_1'(0)}X=D_{r_2'(0)}X$ by expressing $X,v$ using local coordinate $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ around $p$ and apply the axiom of a connection.

But I have trouble showing the other part, that is, given $r:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ be a curve with $r'(0)=v$, and $X,Y$ be two vector fields such that $X(r(t))=Y(r(t))\forall t\in[0,\epsilon)$, then $D_vX=D_vY$.

Since by definition, $D_vX=D_VX(p)$, I don't know how and why we can restrict $X$ on $r(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the definition of $\bigtriangledown_{r'}r'$, which is used in geodesic.

> **Theorem** If $r'(0)=v$, $r(0)=p$, and $V$, $X$, $Y\in\Gamma(TM)$ satisfy
>   $$V_p=v~~~X\circ r(t)=Y\circ r(t)=r'(t)~~\forall t\in I$$
>   then $\bigtriangledown_VX(p)=\bigtriangledown_VY(p)$.

**Proof** We consider the local presentation of $\bigtriangledown$
$$V=V_i\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i},~~X=X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i},~~Y=Y_i\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i},~~r'=\frac{dv_i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}$$

Because $V_p=r'(0)$, we have
$$V_i(p)=\frac{dv_i}{dt}|_0~~~\cdots(1)$$

From $X\circ r(t)=Y\circ r(t)$, we get
$$X_i\circ r(t)=Y_i\circ r(t)~~~\cdots(2)$$

Then we have
$$\bigtriangledown_VX(p)=(V_i(p)X_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+V_i(p)\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial v_i}|_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p$$
$$=(V_i(p)Y_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+\frac{dv_i}{dt}|_0\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial v_i}|_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p~~~\cdots\text{From (1)}$$
$$=(V_i(p)Y_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+\frac{dX_k\circ r}{dt}|_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p~~~\cdots\text{From chain rule}$$
$$=(V_i(p)Y_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+\frac{dY_k\circ r}{dt}|_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p~~~\cdots\text{From (2)}$$
$$=(V_i(p)Y_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+\frac{dv_i}{dt}|_0\frac{\partial Y_k}{\partial v_i}|_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p$$
$$=(V_i(p)X_j(p)\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)+V_i(p)\frac{\partial Y_k}{\partial v_i}|_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial v_k}|_p$$
$$=\bigtriangledown_VY(p)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's easier to understand if I can write like this : let $v^i$ be coordinate functions, and $r(t)=(v^1(t),\cdots v^n(t)), r'=\frac{dx_i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}$, then by chain rule, $\frac{dX_k\circ r_i}{dt}|_0=\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial v_i}|_p\frac{dv_i}{dt}|_0$. So in your answer, you parametrize $r(t)=(r^1(t),\cdots r^n(t))$, do you refer to the same thing?

Comment: @JohnZHANG Oh yes, your comprehension is very right. I will promote my answer.